# Every model, similar code - better way? (CakePHP)

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-model

In nearly every model, I end up writing code **similar** to the below example code.  It checks to see if options like `limit`, `order`, `conditions`...etc  are sent and changes the query based on that.

Just seems like there MUST be a better way, since most of this stuff is duplicated over and over in many models.  Maybe I can use a behavior?  Or maybe something else I'm completely overlooking?

I feel like I've tried to reinvent the wheel as far as the model code is concerned, but I'd really like to know what the wheel IS - ie what do most people do to manage their model code?  I assume it's "normal" for models to be similar like this?  Looking for best practice for this overall "similar model code" concept.

```
//Restaurant model
function getRestaurants($opts = null) {

    //initialize
    $findType = 'all';
    $params['conditions'] = array();    

    //order
    $params['order'] = 'Restaurant.name ASC';
    if(!empty($opts['order'])) $params['order'] = $opts['order'];

    //limit
    if(!empty($opts['limit'])) {
        $params['limit'] = $opts['limit'];
        if($params['limit'] == 1) $findType = 'first';
    }

    /*... ETC ETC
    - can pass conditions, pricing, days open....etc
    - obviously some things are only for this model, but things like
      limit, order, conditions...etc are for all my models
    */

    //pagination
    $paginate = false;
    if(isset($opts['paginate'])) {
        if($opts['paginate']) {
            $paginate = true;
        }
    }

    //either return the paginate options just created
    if($paginate) {
        return $params;

    //or return the restaurant data found
    } else {
        $data = $this->find($findType, $params);
        return $data;
    }
}
```

In some, there are more complicated things like - whether or not to contain/join certain models based on an option sent...etc etc.

I'm trying to stick with the MVC concept and keep all my DB stuff in the models.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the code is the same for all models you could use a behavior and simply attach it to the models and change the query using the beforeFind() callback.

Putting the code into AppModel is also fine and calling it inside the beforeFilter() of the models that need it. But I think the behavior is less work to type. ;) So I would go for the behavior. If you need more fanciness like specific options for a model while having a set of defaults you could simply change the behavior to support that by merging options from a property of the model with the defaults in the behavior. If you would be more specific i could provide a better solution.

And finally: There is no common or 100% right way to do it. I would always choose the solution that stays close to MVC and follows KIS.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, you can put the common things in AppModel

Comment: I undertand/understood that, but not what I'm looking for.

Comment: I think you can implement a method like paginate (implicitly read information from arguments, $paginate and accept extra conditions) in controller. That method will read some conventional information from you parameter, some field in the AppModel or your Model and accept extra conditions in $opts['conditions'] for example.

Comment: That sounds a little more like what I'm thinking - I'd have to imagine I'm not the only one with this situation - is that what people do? If so, are there any example so I can better understand?

Answer (score 0):

You could try extending your similar models to a base class, and write a generic option setter in there.  This could be dependent on how many special cases you have.  For example, in the base class your option setter could deal with whatever arguments are always present, and in a special case you could override the function for whichever models are required.

```
App::import('Model','TheBaseModel');
class YourModel extends TheBaseModel {

}

class TheBaseModel extends AppModel {

    function OptionSetter() {

    }

}
```

Comment: can you clarify "extend similar models to a base class"?

Comment: given the code above, the function `OptionSetter` will be available from `YourModel`, and any generic option building code can be put in there.

Comment: Sounds like a more complicated version of hope_is_grim's answer, since I could just put a function in the AppModel instead of creating a new class to hold it, right?

Comment: Putting it in app_model just means the function will be available to every model instead of only being available to applicable models.  (good practice!)

Comment: Gotcha - thanks.  It seems like it might be worth having in the AppModel for me, but - great to know this way of doing it if I need something more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the previous answer, sounds like you are looking for a way to replicate the same code across multiple models, but customize it for each model.

As recommended, extending AppModel is the recommended way to go. You should probably look into the [Inflector](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/inflector.html) methods to allow it to work for each sub-model.

What I've recently started doing is editing the template files, for the model it would be this (in CakePHP 2.0.x):

```
lib/Cake/Console/Templates/default/classes
```

Open and edit model.ctp, and add your code there.

When you bake your models (which is what I believe you are doing), it will help replicate your exact code in each of the generated models.

Comment: I'm not actually baking, but - sounds more and more like it's just something I put in the AppModel.  I assumed someone would answer with "Oh yeah - that's so common, people usually do THIS". I appreciate your answer... gonna hold out a bit to see if someone has any other ideas, but - you add more weight to the previous answers regarding the AppModel - thanks.

Comment: You're welcome, glad it was at least a bit helpful. :) I make changes to the model.ctp file often to generate custom MVCs, but yeah, I haven't seen that much documentation about others doing it and don't know how commonplace this is.